# posts_per_page not working for first page of pagination

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination

I am displaying WordPress posts on my home page and using pagination for these posts. I am limiting number of posts (10) using `posts_per_page`. But still there are 90+ posts on first page but on all next pages there are correct number of posts (10).
Why on my first page there are still 90+ posts?
Here is my code

```
wp_reset_query(); 
$args = Array('meta_key' => '_imwb_zonpress_post_ctr',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
 'order' => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => 12,
'paged' => get_query_var( 'page' ) ,
);  
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then we have a loop to display all posts. I will appreciate your help for this task. Ty

Comment: visit the link;-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345744/wordpress-pagination-not-working-page-2-same-as-page-1

Comment: do you have 'sticky' posts?

Comment: No these are not sticky posts